# Using { get set } Accessors for Multiple Values in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, accessor

**EDIT:** Question Reconstructed.

OK, I have revisited my get and set methods, but I am still very unclear on how it all works.

What I want to achieve is the Model is populated by the Controller, from the values that it takes form the form. This is then sent to the Db_Facade, which compares the uName and uPwd, and if they are equal returns the ACCESS, which will be set for the entire scope of the program.

I don't know if the get and set declarations are done correctly, or if they can be bunched together (If this is possible it would be great because I will be using this for much larger collections of data), and I'm pretty sure I'm implementing them wrong as well.

If you can help, my knowledge of Accessors is incredibly limited.

Here is my Compare Login method in my Controller:

```
    public static void Compare_Login(User_Login_View Login_View)
    {
        User_Model getACCESS = new User_Model(); // Creates a new oject of User_Model
        getACCESS.Name = Login_View.txtUsername.Text; //Populates the Model from the Login View
        getACCESS.Pwd = Login_View.txtPassword.Text;

        if (getACCESS.ACCESSLEVEL > 0)
        {
            Login_View.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Login_View.lblError.Visible = true;
        }
        Login_View.Menu.SetMenuView();
    }
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class User_Model
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Db_Facade.uName;
        }
        set
        {
            Db_Facade.uName = value;
        }
    }

    public string Pwd
    {
        get
        {
            return Db_Facade.uPwd;
        }
        set
        {
            Db_Facade.uPwd = value;
        }
    }

    public int ACCESSLEVEL
    {
        get
        {
            return Db_Facade.ACCESS;
        }
        set
        {
            Db_Facade.ACCESS = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the dummy database comparison:

```
class Db_Facade
{
    public static string uName;
    public static string uPwd;
    public static string cPwd;
    public static int ACCESS;

    public static void getLoginACCESS()
    {
        uName = "paul";
        uPwd = "pwd";
        ACCESS = 1;
     /* I get a "getACCESS does not exist" error here
        if (uName == getACCESS.Name && uPwd == getACCESS.Pwd)
        {
            getACCESS.ACCESSLEVEL = ACCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            getACCESS.ACCESSLEVEL = 0;
        }
      */
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's needed, but here is my View

```
public partial class User_Login_View : Form
{
    public Menu_View Menu { get; set; }
    public User_Login_View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User_Controller.Compare_Login(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't understand what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Show us your view model. From what I can gather here... you are doing it completely wrong.

Comment: When I click on my login button on the form, the Compare Login method fills the Model. I then want to send the model to the Db_Facade, compare the values uName and uPwd, then return the ACCESS variable to be set for the SetMenuView method. Does that explain it?

Comment: What error/exception you are getting ?

Comment: @Arun I haven't been recording errors, since I have tried many different approaches and none have worked.

Comment: no one can help you, if you can't help yourself.
Your question doesn't make any sense

Comment: I understand that this question is extremely vague, but my understanding of this is minimal at best. If anything I'm looking for a way to use the get and set accessors to compare or store data between two different classes.

Comment: They are properties. They are no different to using fields from a consumers point of view. I still don't understand exactly what the issue is. Perhaps rephrasing will help? Or a smaller sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Questions / Hints

1.) Where do you call your `getLoginACCESS()` ?

2.) Why do you think `Db_Facade` is able to access `getACCESS`from your class `User_Controller`?

a solution would be to modyfie your `getLoginACCESS()` to `getLoginACCESS(User_Model getACCESS)` and than call it in your `Compare_Login(User_Login_View Login_View)` befor your `if` like `Db_Facade.etLoginACCESS(getACCESS);`

Comment: ok well that cleared up my errors (thanks for reminding me about the calls). For some reason the comparison isn't working properly (it returns ACCESS 1 with or without correct uName and uPwd) but I'll fix that up. But I don't think this is implementing the Accessors properly?

Comment: it's because you are override your Values in your Db_Facade (User_Model and Db_Facade has at any time the same values) to avoid this replace your `{get{...}set{..}}` with `{get;set;}` and it should work

Comment: Ok so I did that, and now it is picking up valid or invalid data, but it is not returning ACCESS at all?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, got it working (I wasn't following my own naming conventions properly haha). Thanks for the assistance :)